# Binding a checkbox to an elements visibility via XAML only

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I do not understand why the binding does not work like this?

```
<UserControl>
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox x:Name="CBTempA"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            <Label VerticalAlignment="Center">Temp A</Label>
        </StackPanel>
        <lvc:CartesianChart>
            <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
                <lvc:LineSeries Values="{Binding TempAValues}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=CBTempA, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

The converter `BoolToVisibility` converts a boolean value (`IsChecked`) into a System.Windows.Visibility value. It may look something like this:

```cs
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // value is a parameter from xaml (IsChecked)
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            return (bool) value ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The converter works fine, I already use this successfully with other elements. So this is not the problem.

Comment: Try `Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference CBTempA}, Path=IsChecked,..."` instead of `ElementName`. Maybe there are context problems within your chart.